# Looking for a project management tool that would serve as a mix of Scrum and Kanban

Tags: web-apps, project-management

I have a medium sized team, no more than 15 people at all times and I am looking for a tool that is a mix between Scrum and Kanban (we are not consistent on one methodology).

Besides that the tool should:

- be Web based
- allow time tracking
- allow backlog management
- generate reports
- be user friendly

Additional features always welcome.

Comment: Please provide additional information.  A list of requirements will be helpful.  You want a tool that supports scrum and kanban...there are lots.  Give some more specifics and the answers will come.

Comment: What @James said. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for some extra suggestions.

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/3171/110

Comment: Self-hosted or an external service? Pricing?

Answer (score 5):

I have also researched a few tools myself and would like to share what I have found so far.

[image]

[Urban Turtle](http://urbanturtle.com/) pros – product backlog tree view, integration with TFS, includes both methodologies. Cons – busy interface, lack of visual appeal and ease of use, no time tracking and file attaching, lack of flexibility. Pricing $8-6 per user/per month for a yearly subscription, depending on the number of users.

[Eylean Board](http://www.eylean.com/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=text&utm_campaign=DMaction) pros – easy to use, visual, flexible, integration with TFS, MS Project, Outlook, fast to learn. Most beautiful design. Cons – runs only on Windows. Pricing: free for personal use, $12.49 per user/per month for team edition.

[LeanKit](http://leankit.com/) pros – available on various devices and platforms, user-friendly interface, mobility, cons – covers a narrow spectrum of functionalities, only suitable for Kanban practices. Pricing free for up to 10 users, $15 or $19 per user/per month depending on package.

[Scrumwise](https://www.scrumwise.com/) pros – easy to use interface, includes various functionality, cons – lacks reports, lacks flexibility towards user preferences (for example -backlog placement cannot be changed). Pricing $9 per user/per month.

[Kanbanize](https://kanbanize.com/) pros – clean interface, easy to use, multiple platforms, cons – does not include scrum, lacks certain functionality. Pricing from $9 for 5 users/per month to $249 for 100 users/per month.

Answer (score 3):

For the development of http://GTDNext.com we have been using http://yodiz.com

It is a very complete solution.  I recommend it highly!

Answer (score 3):

we use a online application called [Kanban Tool](http://kanbantool.com/). It provides all features you want:

- it is web based,
- it offers seamless time tracking,
- it allows backlog management,
- the application provides analytcs: CFD, Lead and Cycle Time Diagram, Time tracking reports,
- it is very use friendly, easy to use, customize (with Power-ups) and integrate with other systems (via API) and services (Zapier).

It is worth trying out.

Answer (score 2):

We used [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) in one of the companies I worked for, and I found a really nice P.M. tool. It's web-based, open-source, and cross-database, and it has all the features that you want.

Some of its main features are:

- Multiple projects support
- Flexible role based access control
- Flexible issue tracking system
- Gantt chart and calendar
- News, documents & files management
- Feeds & email notifications
- Per project wiki
- Per project forums
- Time tracking
- Custom fields for issues, time-entries, projects and users
- SCM integration (SVN, CVS, Git, Mercurial, Bazaar and Darcs)
- Issue creation via email
- Multiple LDAP authentication support
- User self-registration support
- Multilanguage support
- Multiple databases support

And you can install any plug-ins for it to support both [Kanban](https://github.com/edavis10/redmine_kanban) and [Scrum](https://github.com/256MbTeam/Redmine-Scrumbler).

There's an expanded list of other plug-ins for Scrum and Kanban [here](http://www.scrumexpert.com/tools/scrum-and-kanban-plugins-for-redmine/).

Answer (score 2):

I'm one of the founders over at ScrumDo, and I think we exactly meet those requirements!

- be Web based - Yes!
- allow time tracking - Yes!
- allow backlog management - Yes!
- generate reports - Yes!
- be user friendly - Yes!

https://www.scrumdo.com/

We fully support Scrum, and have been working on Kanban and Scrumban features for the past 6 months.  We make it easy to mix and match the practices you want.

For anyone interested in that Scrum/Kanban mix, our other founder also recently published a Scrumban book: http://www.scrumban.io/

Comment: I love the ScrumDo, its best Agile tool I ever used to manage projects, it is best for both small size team and large teams.

Answer (score 1):

We use Rally.  [Rally Website](http://www.rallydev.com/)

Rally covers both scrum and kanban.  There are more graphical "notecard views" as well as list views for content.  The interface is very easy.  Promoting a story to a different state can be as simple as drag and drop to the next column.

**be Web based**

Rally is Hosted (or at least that is the option we utilize)

**allow time tracking**

Rally can track time at the story/defect/task/feature/epic levels

**allow backlog management**

Items in a backlog state are listed in priority order, priority can be adjusted by simple drag and drop**

**generate reports**

There are built in reports for things like iteration burndown, more complex queries can be managed by custom views, or accessing data via the Rally API (which is pretty well documented)  There is also a free plug-in for excel that connects you to the Rally database from excel and allows you to generate reports directly in excel, its very handy and pretty easy to pick up.

**be user friendly**

Very simple to use out of the box.  As with any software the more you customize and dictate process it can get complicated.

Comment: Time tracking in rally is too painful to actually work

Comment: What about it do you find painful?

Comment: many use time trackers for active tracking, away monitoring and precise measures. Passive way of tracking time in separate page from the board is not a nice option, unless I am not familiar well enough with other abilities of rally

Comment: @VidasVasiliauskas there are ways to make it easier with custom views/mass edit etc.  But it sounds like you have a 3rd party tracker?

Answer (score 1):

Redmine and TFS (customized to environment)

Redmine

- Open Source
- Web or Local
- Project Level, sub Project or Sprint (as a mini project)!tracking
- Extensive reporting capabilities (don't kill your agile team with this)
- Snap ins for easy time logging
- Effective Bug management
- PB / PBI's
- Huge list of add ons
- Redmine Community - for me very valuable
- Easy integration with CI and Build tools

Easy to use , Wiki actually works as intended

Comment: including links is much better ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to have a look at Proofhub. It is web based project management tool and allows time tracking too. It has native Reports section and it is very easy to use because of its simple UI design. You can explore more at: https://www.proofhub.com/?ref=bk

Answer (score 0):

There are not many options that truly support so called "Scrumban". Essence is the flexibility of Kanban boards to represent swimlanes, allow iteration type planning and have a convenient enough process to pull work for larger scoped projects.

If you need a very simple approach to task management, then go for https://trello.com

Otherwise you might consider these targeted scrumban solutions:

**Teamhood** - https://teamhood.com
[image]

**Eylean Board** - https://www.eylean.com
[image]